# How do we deal with big-list type questions on this site?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

As we know, big-list type questions are not very suitable for the Stack Exchange Q&A format. The answers to such questions to some degree depend subjective opinions and often, there is no definitive answer. However, some sites like [Physics SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4561/good-list-bad-list) have figured out policies to deal with such questions. Of course, certain big-list type questions like [What are the methods of quantum computation?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/74/what-are-the-methods-of-quantum-computation) with a great set of answers can be very useful to the community as a whole, while some others like [this one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/87/practical-ways-to-reduce-quantum-noise): not so much.

When I came across the question: [How to make qubits more stable towards noise?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-to-make-qubits-more-stable-towards-noise), yesterday, I was pretty much in a dilemma whether to vote to close or not. Finally I decided to do so after some pondering, because the question isn't specific at all! [Mithrandir's comment](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-to-make-qubits-more-stable-towards-noise#comment213_63) sums it up well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Big-list** questions should be permitted, provided they're *specific* enough.

> What are the current models of physical realization of quantum computers - like superconducting quantum computing, trapped ion quantum computing, etc.?

For example, the above question would be **on-topic** and not **too broad**. An example of a similar question is [Dependency of architecture on hardware](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/180/dependency-of-architecture-on-hardware/1184#1184).

However, something like: [How to make qubits more stable towards noise?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-to-make-qubits-more-stable-towards-noise) is a **big-list** question which fits into the **too broad** category, as the papers linked in the question talk about different types of noise. The method necessary to make qubits stable depends on both - the *type* of noise and the *cause* of noise. So, unless the original poster makes it clear as to which type of noise and qubit system they're referring to, the question has too many possible answers or requires an answer which would have be way [too lengthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447/437611). In such cases, the concerned question should indeed be [closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/437611) as **too broad**.